# Pass three commands to intersect in R

Tags: r

I am using the intersect function, and was wondering if there is any way to pass three commands rather than just two: i.e

```
colnames(df[ intersect ( grep("name",colnames(df) ), grep("name",colnames(df) ), grep("name",colnames(df),invert=TRUE)   )])
```

This is giving me an error:

```
Error in base::intersect(x, y, ...)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have realised intersect is associative so you can put one inside of another:

```
colnames(df[ intersect (intersect ( grep("name",colnames(df) ), grep("name",colnames(df))), grep("name",colnames(df),invert=TRUE)   )])
```

Comment: Good thinking, but as you see, there are faster & cleaner ways (Roland's answer)

Answer (score 4):

Use `Reduce`:

```
x <- letters[1:5]
y <- letters[2:6]
z <- letters[3:7]

Reduce(intersect, list(x, y, z))
#[1] "c" "d" "e"
```

Comment: How would you use this method with a function?

Comment: I don't understand. The first argument of `Reduce` must always be a (binary) function.

Comment: How could I write this to perform three grep actions?